# IOS Swift fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, option-type

I'm a beginner in IOS programming and in whole programming.

(I have a XCODE 6.4)

I have a code in my TableViewController in which a have a data, which I want to pass to another viewController. I was reading a lot about it in internet and than I have written this code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let identifier = "formuleTableViewCell"

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! formule



    let formuleCommand = formulesList[indexPath.row]

    // Configure the cell...

    var shortCut = formuleCommand.formuleText

    cell.formuleLabel.text = shortCut



    return cell
}






var valueToPass:String!

func tablView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    println("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")

    // Get Cell Label
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow();
    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as UITableViewCell!;

    let identifier = "formuleTableViewCell"

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier, forIndexPath: indexPath!) as! formule

    valueToPass = cell.formuleLabel.text
    performSegueWithIdentifier("detail", sender: self)

}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if (segue.identifier == "detail") {

        // initialize new view controller and cast it as your view controller
       var viewController = segue.destinationViewController as! specialitiesViewController
        // your new view controller should have property that will store passed value
        viewController.passedValue = valueToPass
    }

}
```

In my TableViewController I have cells, that contains labels with some data. I want to pass data from this labels to another ViewController. And when i run my app, there is no errors, but when I click on one of the cells, which have to move me to another ViewController (I have setted a segue for this) prints an error  : `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`
And app crashes. Help me to fix this error please!

Thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

You've got `valueToPass` defined as an implicitly unwrapped optional - i.e., you're telling iOS there is always going to be a value here.

So when `prepareForSegue` is called, and you haven't set `valueToPass` to anything, it will fail. You should initialise it with some value.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using this code to open up your view controller (If you have a class for the VC you want to open).

```
let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("your_Storyboard_id") as! Your_VC_Class
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you won't know the value of `valueToPass` at initialization but *may* know the value at some time later, you should make valueToPass an optional:

`var valueToPass: String?`

...and then deal with unwrapping it when you need it and handling the case where it's not initialized appropriately.

If you won't know the value of `valueToPass` at initialization but *will* know the value by the time the view controller is presented, then you should leave it as an implicitly unwrapped optional (i.e. as is) but ensure you set it to a valid value before use.

Side note: Generally speaking it's better to us `as?` than `as!` and handle the case where the cast did not work.